# How to only pass specific solution bindings from the default graph to the VALUES clause of the federated query?

Tags: sparql, rdflib

In the following SPARQL query, solutions of both the variables, `?citizenship_uri` and `?place_of_birth` are passed to the `VALUES` clause of the federated query.

```
PREFIX person: <http://www.w3.org/ns/person#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT ?place_of_birth ?citizenship        
WHERE {
 [] person:citizenship ?citizenship_uri ;
    person:placeOfBirth ?place_of_birth .
                          
  SERVICE <https://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql> {
      ?citizenship_uri skos:prefLabel ?citizenship .
       FILTER(LANG(?citizenship) = "en")
  }
}
```

The below is the federated query performed by the RDFLib where both the solution bindings are present in the `VALUES`. However, the `place_of_birth` is not required here, since it is not used in the federated query.

```
# Federated query

PREFIX person: <http://www.w3.org/ns/person#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT REDUCED * WHERE {
                    ?citizenship_uri skos:prefLabel ?citizenship .
                    FILTER(LANG(?citizenship) = "en")
                  }VALUES (?citizenship_uri ?place_of_birth) {(<http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/country/GBR> "London")}
```

How can I capture the `?place_of_birth` without it being included in the VALUES clause of the federated query?

I get the following error from the SPARQL endpoint if the unused solution bindings are included in the federated query's VALUES clause.

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable name 'place_of_birth' is used in the BINDINGS clause but not in the query result set
```

Comment: you don't have control how `rdflib`does pass value bindings to the federated query. The problem here is more that the backend (here Virtuoso 7.x) is a bit picky as the SPARQL query itself is valid. In Virtuoso 8.x that exception won't occur, so they might have fixed the bug in newer versions. Doesn't help you here though ...

Comment: the evaluation of the `SERVICE` clause happens here: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/main/rdflib/plugins/sparql/evaluate.py#L336 - I don't think you could overwrite or modify this, e.g. putting the `VALUES` clause inside the query might already help